# List directories in Batch

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, recursion

I have multiple folders with a structure like this inside:

```
aaa
    000
        important
            v001
            v002
            v003
        not_important
            something_else
    001
        important
            v001
            v002
            v003
        not_important
            something_else
    002
        important
            v001
            v002
            v003
        not_important
            something_else
bbb
    000
        important
            v001
            v002
            v003
        not_important
            something_else
    001
        important
            v003
        not_important
            something_else
    002
        important
            v001
            v002
            v003
        not_important
            something_else
ccc
    000
        important
            v001
            v002
            v003
        not_important
            something_else
    001
        important
            v001
            v002
            v003
            v004
            v005
        not_important
            something_else
    002
        important
            v001
            v002
            v003
        not_important
            something_else
```

One of the folders is called `v00?`, which contains a specific version of a file.
Now I want to list all the dates of the latest files.

However here are my problems:

- I assume I cant use a recursive function, because I have some folders that I don't care about (not_important in my example above)
- I only want the lastest Version
- The versions don't always start at one and are not limited by number
- The Folder names are not an easy aaa, bbb, 000, structure and cannot be looped by name, the also not nessecarily repeat (Folder1 and Folder2 are not the same, just the amount of folders/layers that they go in)
  -I need to iterate through the outer folders as well.

How can I only filter out the latest Version of these folders?

I tried this, however I can't get multiple layers in with that function
and the "dir" command gives me everything

```
"FOR /D %%d IN (*.*) DO ("
```

How can I solve this?

My current code looks like this>

```
@echo off

setlocal 

for /D %%d in (*.*) do (
    echo %%d
    cd %%d

        for /D %%e in (*.*) do (
        echo %%e
        cd %%e
                for /D %%f in (*.*) do (
                    cd %%f
                    echo %%f



                    Insert Here CD ??



                    for /f "tokens=*" %%1 in ('dir /b /ad /on v*') do (
                        set latestdir=%%1
                    )

                    echo Latest directory name=%latestdir%

                        cd %latestdir%\fullres
                            pause
                        cd..


                )
        cd..
        )
    cd ..

)
pause
```

Comment: how do you determine what files you want? you have listed things that are NOT usable for filtering ... so what IS usable for a filter?

Comment: I want all the files in the important folder with the last version on it, where the folder has been created within the last 7 days - at the moment I fail at entering the important folder where the cd important doesn not work

Comment: so ... is the folder actually named `important`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /r /d %%A in (\v00*) do (
    pushd "%%~A\.."
    for /d %%B in (v00*) do set "subfolder=%%~B"
    if not "!save!" == "!cd!" echo !cd!\!subfolder!
    set "save=!cd!"
    popd
)
```

This recurses through all the directories in the *current
directory* and searches for a match of `\v00*`. It will
`pushd` into each *matched directory parent dir* found and
then the nested `for` loop searches for the last matching
subfolder of `v00*`. If the *saved current directory*
does not match the *current directory* then the matched
directory path will be echoed. The *current directory*
will be saved for the next loop and `popd` will return
to the initial directory.